# SQL Substract 2 colums in same table

Tags: php, sql

I've table named 'detail_transaksi'. I want to SUM all of the data in "jumlah" column where "debit_kredit" = 'D' which is grouped in the same "kode_akun" data. Also, I want to SUM all of the data in "jumlah" column where "debit_kredit" = 'K' which is grouped in the same "kode_akun" data. Then, I want to SUBSTRACT both of them. How can I do it in SQL or maybe in PHP?

[image]

Here's columns in my table:

```
id
kode_transaksi
kode_akun
debit_kredit
jumlah
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select kode_akun,
       sum(case when debit_kredit = 'K' then jumlah
                when debit_kredit = 'D' then - jumlah
           end)
from detail_transaksi
group by kode_akun;
```

Comment: Thank u so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY debit_kredit to grouping SUM of records by debit_kredit value
and after that, you can do subtract or whatever you want on your data.

```
SELECT debit_kredit , SUM(jumlah) AS total_sum FROM detail_transaksi GROUP BY debit_kredit
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum if for both K and D in debit_kredit

The following should achieve that.

```
SELECT
  kode_akun,
  SUM(CASE WHEN debit_kredit='K' then jumlah else 0 end) as jumlah_k,
  SUM(CASE WHEN debit_kredit='D' then jumlah else 0 end) as jumlah_d,
FROM detail_transaksi GROUP BY kode_akun
```

As for the difference between jumlah_k and jumlah_d you would have to subtract the sum expressions,this is rather inefficient, I would advice you to do that in php